# Top accent position of OTF math font in XeTeX and LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, luaotfload

MWE:

```
% Xe-/LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=literal]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

$\dot b, \dot  , \dot{\rm b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The accent placement seems to be wrong, in my opinion. The `\dot{\rm b}` example seems to be right. How to get this as the default behaviour?

OK, in LuaTeX we can change the `top_accent` values of the OTF table, as Marcel Krüger has done:
[Fixing the position of math accents when using unicode-math in lualatex with a text font for letters and digits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568343/fixing-the-position-of-math-accents-when-using-unicode-math-in-lualatex-with-a-t)

But is there a simpler solution? In this answer a faked math font is used, but I would like to patch a real math font. So some lines of code can be omitted, can't they?

What about XeTeX? Is there a solution, too? Are the `top_accent` values represented by a `\fontdimen`?

Comment: `\rm` hasn't been defined in latex by default since 1993, surprising to see it in a lualatex document.

Comment: OK, I use Plain TeX, but the MWE is much shorter in LaTeX. ;)

Comment: I saw this comment after I had posted a latex answer.

Comment: No problem. What I mean is that I would like the dot to be placed in the middle over the `b`, not on the left side. And this happens in the "forbidden" `\rm` solution.

Comment: oh actually I misread your question, the placement over the Roman d looked so obviously wrong I posted a solution with the standard placement over that. I didn't notice you were asking to have that placement over the italic d as well.

Comment: I extended my answer with this centred dot setting.

Comment: Thank you. But does it really look wrong? Try with a wider accent. ;) `\vec b` and `\ddddot b` look horrible. The half of vector arrow does not cover the `b`. Compare it also to `\vec b` with `tfm` math fonts. ;)

Comment: @WeißerKater Do you only want this for `b` or do you want to get accents over all characters centered?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger For upright characters the accents should be centered. For italic characters it would be nice if the middle of the accents were above the slant axis.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The dot is positioned over the stem of the d as specified in the font but if you want it centred over the whole character for some reason then you can make the base be more than a single character and let tex position a centred accent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=literal]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

$\dot b, \dot  , \dot{\symrm{b}}$

$\dot{b{}}, \dot {{}}, \dot{\symrm{b}{}}$

\end{document}
```

`\rm` is a legacy command that is not defined by default in latex but defined in some classes for compatibilty with LaTeX2.09 documents.